# URL to PHP file not working

Tags: php, html, xampp, href

I'm trying to learn HTML and PHP so trying to build a login form with some links.

The bebsite opens OK, however the link to sign up seems to be going nowhere.

My index file as follows:

```
<?php
 include ('../app/header.php');
 ?>
    <section class="main-container">
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
     </section>
 <?php
   include ('../app/footer.php');
 ?>
```

And my header php as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nav-login">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username\e-mail">
          <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
          <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <a href="../app/signup.php">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The issue is that `href` link to signup php takes me nowhere. However if I copy the files into public directory and change the path in the link it then works fine.

Also, after clicking signup link, my URL shows localhost\app\signup.php.

Im using **xammp**.

Could someone advise as to why the link does not work as expected?

Thanks

UPDATED:

My directory is as follows:

C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\public\index.php

and all PHP files are here:

C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\app

Comment: Please, show your directory structure, in particular where the index file is and where the `signup.php` file is relative to it

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that the URL should be `'/signup.php'` i can't be certain though

Comment: added path as requested @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: If you want the browser to request a file, it must be visible for the user through the webserver (public). Every php page is an entry point...

Comment: Dale if i state it would indicate signup php is in the public folder which is not

Comment: True but you hadn't included the highly important info about your directory structure when I commented so it was a pure stab in the dark

Comment: I don't know xampp, but I have a hunch that your `app` folder should be under `public`

Comment: @frederico I though only key files should be kept under public folder and all key files should be hidden from public. Am I right?

Comment: The approach you're going for isn't a bad approach at all, keep the files out of the public folder is a nice idea, but now you're going to run into the issue of none public files, which needs server rewrites enabled, youll have to learn about htaccess files if youre using xampp, plus some way to include said file in your index.php template, probably going to be easier right now to move the app folder under public, you'll also need to create a name based virtual host so you can access the site like "http://mysite.dev" which actually points back to localhost.. yea.. go with moving the app folder

Comment: If it works like I think, every file the client may need to access (in this case, it needs to access signup.php) should be in a folder that is accessible (i.e. under the document root, that is `public`)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for that. Does this mean there is no way around it? I read about alias in the server config files but prefer not to go this root.

Comment: It's too long to answer properly, but if "signup.php" contains code that you don't want in the public folder, use it as a container for functions it needs to provide and then add calls to those functions inside a file in the document root, and point your links to this file.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca. I think I understand. I will play around with functions then. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understood so far these are your folders:

```
// site
   // app
      signup.php
   // public
      index.php
```

Your http server is using the `public` folder as *doc root*, therefore accessing `http://localhost/index.php` is the same as `public/index.php`.

If you link to `../app/signup.php` **your browser** will attempt to access `http://localhost/../app/signup.php`, since you can't request files outside your *doc root* it will not find your file.

That's not exclusive to php, apache or even xampp but is true for all http servers.

For it to work, all your system's entry points (like index and signup) must be made public for the browsers.

Moving your file to `public/signup.php` and updating the link will work.

Comment: This is what I have though. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: updated with a solution: move your signup.php to public/ and link normally.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to correctly understand how to use Absolute and Relative paths ([this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) is a rapid reference at W3S) and - as [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) wrote in the first comment - check your directory structure to verify that the paths correctly point to the resources you want to link.

Moreover, please note that your `<form>` is not sending any data to your signup.php script. You have to specify an action and eventually a method to do this as in:

```
<form action='/app/signup.php' method='post'>
... your input fields here ...
... your submit button ...
</form>
```

Comment: it does not at the moment but my next step is to connect to DB and write a signup script which I will define as an action. I understand the relative paths etc but wasn't too sure why I could not access upper folder this way. I now understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out.

Created a new php file in the public folder which contains an include statement as per below:

```
<?php include ('../app/signup.php') ?>
```

where my original link calls as follows:

```
<a href="signup_form.php">Sign up</a>`
```